# Un doute sur un passé simple

Tags: grammaire, concordance-des-temps

Devrais-je écrire:

> Je passai l'aspirateur très tôt le matin. J’avais déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui avait été bien fatiguant.

plutôt que:

> Je passai l'aspirateur très tôt le matin. J’avais déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui fût bien fatiguant.

J'ai l'impression que la concordance des temps est plus correcte dans la première phrase, mais il ne me paraît pas évident que la deuxième soit complètement fausse.

**Note**: j'ai mis la question à jour pour fournir plus de contexte et ainsi justifier l'usage du plus-que-parfait dans la principale.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145572/discussion-on-question-by-frank-un-doute-sur-un-passe-simple)** for readability/organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux phrases ne sont pas très naturelles. Voici ce qui me semble plus idiomatique:

> *Ce* matin-là, je passai l'aspirateur très tôt. J’avais déjà aspiré le canapé *la veille*, ce qui **avait été** bien *fatigant*.

Comment: Trés bien. Je vais retenir cette réponse.

Answer (score 0):

> J’avais déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui avait été bien fatiguant.

Le temps de la principale ne correspond pas au contexte (hier) :  Le plus-que-parfait sert à décrire une action passée qui est arrivée avant une autre action passée.

Il faut donc un passé composé.

- J’ai déjà aspiré le canapé hier.

Il n'est donc pas question d'un plus que parfait dans la relative. Il reste la possibilité d'un passé composé (circonstances simultanés) ou d'un passé simple.

- J’ai déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui a été bien fatiguant.
- J’ai déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui fut bien fatiguant.

Un imparfait dans la relative ne convient pas parce que l'imparfait exprime une action non achevée. Dans la phrase suivante l'imparfait serait correct.

- J’ aspirais le canapé hier, ce qui était bien fatiguant.

L'utilisation d'un plus que parfait avec  « hier » reste possible, mais il faut que « hier » soit la dénotation d'un fait passé par rapport à un autre fait passé.

- J'ai encore passé l'aspirateur sur le canapé cet après-midi, alors que  je l'avais déjà fait  hier, mais le chien ne nous écoute pas, il ne veut pas aller dormir ailleurs.

Si un contexte différent est ajouté, le plus que parfait est correct et le passé simple aussi.

- J'ai passé l'aspirateur aujourd'hui ; j’avais déjà aspiré le canapé hier, ce qui avait été/fut bien fatiguant.

ex.

- Mes yeux ne s'étaient pas encore habitués à la pénombre, mais j'avançai tout de même à l'aveugle dans le couloir. ([réf.](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/le-plus-que-parfait-de-l-indicatif-f1201))
- Mes yeux ne s'étaient pas encore habitués à la pénombre, mais j'avais avancé à l'aveugle dans le couloir.

Comment: hmmmm - "J’ai déjà aspiré le canapé hier" n'est pas aussi nécessaire que vous le dites. Cela dépend du contexte, comme l'a fait remarquer guillaume31. Ce passé composé change complètement l'effet narratif.

Comment: @Frank On est bien obligé de considérer le contexte donné : c'est une entré en matière. Ensuite on peut penser à un contexte différent et c'est ce que je fais, mais ça c'est en plus, c'est ce qui permet de faire des comparaisons et de ce fait de mieux assimiler les principes. Dans le contexte donné le plus que parfait de la principale ne convient pas, à moins qu'il me manque une notion.

Comment: la question est plutôt: supposez que "j’avais déjà aspiré le canapé hier" est justifié par le contexte. Quelle option convient le mieux: la 1, ou la 2?

Comment: J'ai ajouté un contexte.

Comment: "Le temps de la principale ne correspond pas au contexte (hier) : Le plus-que-parfait sert à décrire une action passée qui est arrivée avant une autre action passée" - ce n'est pas seulement "hier" qui est en jeu. On peut très bien dire: "je l'avais vu hier, avant d'aller au cinéma".